# Remove the "default.jsp" from URL in Tomcat with the web.xml file

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tomcat

I've a project where I can't use Apache for redirect, and I want to masquerade or remove the filename "default.jsp" from the URI in any subfolder of an specific application. With the .htaccess is easy, but I don't know any way to do the same in Tomcat...

What i¡m doing in other servers where I can manage the apache is:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*default\.jsp [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)default\.jsp/*(.*) $1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#How_do_I_override_the_default_home_page_loaded_by_Tomcat.3F, you can define in the config file `$TOMCAT_HOME/conf/web.xml` the default page to be accessed.

Comment: thanks you, but that link explains how to set the default page for a directory but what i need is a way to change the hide the default.jsp into the URL, but show it.

Comment: What about redirecting the welcome page to your default JSP page? http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_page_redirect.htm